# Error: Cannot find module 'update-notifier'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Everytime time I run `npm` on mac terminal, I've got this error

```
Mac01:~ qa$ npm
module.js:515
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'update-notifier'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:513:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:463:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:556:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:29:19
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:92:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:612:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
```

-> http://prntscr.com/h1r3yu

how can i solve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ran into this issue. Even a simple `npm --version` was bombing with the same message. This lead me on a wild goose chase of brew uninstalls,  symlink errors, rm's to remove files /node_modules/npm & /node,  chowning directories -- you get the gist. Unsure the root cause of my brew-failings, but it *might* be related to npm being installed as standalone prior, whereas node now includes npm, which lead to brew config-hell on my machine.
I suggest the tips above, but if all else fails, what worked for me was to uninstall via brew, then go to the https://nodejs.org/en/download site and re-install. Believe me, I don't want to get out of terminal and not use brew, but in this case, this was the only solution that worked for me.

- Uninstall node via brew : `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node` or `brew uninstall --force node`
- Go to `https://nodejs.org/en/download` download and reinstall.
- Now test to see if the error is gone with a `npm --version`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue before with the module update-notifier and then I solved the error by installing it globally

Try installing the update-notifier

```
 npm install update-notifier
```

If you need more information, you can click on this [update-notifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/update-notifier)

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem because I installed nodejs from distro and by nvm, as solution I just removed the nodejs from disto. Since I'm using fedora the command was this: `sudo dnf remove -y nodejs npm`. Also make sure that nvm is being sourced at your shell *rc*. Here is `~/.zshrc` which works for bash too:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This     loads nvm bash_completion
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nvm and node 9.5.0, you can solve this problem by running:

`nvm use --delete-prefix v9.5.0 --silent`

Answer (score -3):

Try to do this `npm install -g update-notifier`

**UPD**

Try to reinstall node with npm:

```
brew uninstall node;
# or `brew uninstall --force node` which removes all versions
brew prune;
rm -f /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d;
rm -rf ~/.npm;
```

To install:

```
brew install node;
which node # => /usr/local/bin/node
export NODE_PATH='/usr/local/lib/node_modules' # <--- add this ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Try to reinstall node with npm:

`brew uninstall node; `
# or `brew uninstall --force node` which removes all versions
brew prune;
rm -f /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d;
rm -rf ~/.npm;
To install:

brew install node;
which node # => /usr/local/bin/node
export NODE_PATH='/usr/local/lib/node_modules' # <--- add this ~/.bashrc

Comment: I don't understand that @Rostislav, can you post that as an answer? with step by step procedure?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: what do you mean by this command `export NODE_PATH='/usr/local/lib/node_modules' # <--- add this ~/.bashrc'

Comment: I mean, open file `~/.bashrc` in vim, for example: `vi ~/.bashrc`, and add line  `export NODE_PATH='/usr/local/lib/node_modules` in this file if this line doesn't exist there.

Comment: thanks for your help, i already solved it by installing node.js pkg instead in terminal command